# How to have an input function similar to Shell Input () for Tkinter Entrybox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a chatbot (called JARVIS), where the user can talk to jarvis. I created a GUI using tinker, with a chat window. I just want to allow the user to enter something in the entry box, which can respond to my codes for example:

```
JARVIS: what is your name?
USER: Vincent
JARVIS: Hello Vincent!
```

Basically I need an input function in my Tkinkter entrybox

This is what I got so far (you may understand what I am saying by running code):
I don't want to change my code much, but any suggestions to clean it up a bit is very welcome.

```
#imports
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()

def cbc(id, tex):
    return lambda : callback(id, tex)
#button user
def callback(id, tex):
    d = 'USER:' + e.get() + '\n'
    tex.insert(tk.END, d)
    tex.see(tk.END)
    e.delete(0, 'end')
#jarvis's words
def jarvisprint(words):
    jarvissay = 'JARVIS:' + str(words) + '\n'
    tex.insert(tk.END, jarvissay)
    tex.tag_add("start", "end -" + str(len(jarvissay) +1) + " chars", 'end -1 lines') #change if colour
    tex.tag_config("start", foreground="black")
    tex.see(tk.END)
#enter user
def returnev(event):
    d = 'USER:' + e.get() + '\n'
    tex.insert(tk.END, d)
    tex.see(tk.END)
    e.delete(0, 'end')

def refresh():
    tex.delete('1.0', 'end')
#--------------------------- textbox
tex = tk.Text(master=root, width=40, fg='blue')
tex.pack(side=tk.TOP)
bop = tk.Frame()
bop.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
#--------------------------- entry box
e = Entry(root)
e.pack(fill = X)
e.focus_set()
e.bind('<Return>', returnev)
#---------------------------send button
b = tk.Button(root, text="send", command=cbc(1, tex))
b.pack()
c = tk.Button(root, text="refresh", command= refresh)
c.pack()
#------CODING-----------------------

jarvisprint("What is your name?")
x = 45
y = 92
z = x + y
jarvisprint(z)
#I WANT TO INSERT AN INPUT FUNCTION HERE E.G. ageVar = str(input("how old are you?"))

#so the user will insert age in the entry box in tkinter

#then call it here>>>>>>>> jarvisprint("you are " + ageVar)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For those of us who don't know what Shell Input () does/implies, what exactly to you do want the `tkinter.Entry` widget to do?

Comment: basically be able to have this convo in tkinter: JARVIS: what is your name?
USER (Types): Vincent
JARVIS: Hello Vincent!

Comment: as shown above in my post

Comment: An `Entry` widget is to let the user see and modify a _single_ line of text. If you want to display multiple lines of text that can be edited, you'll need to use a [`Text`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text.html) widget.

Comment: please try to run my program above and you will undestand what I mean by the conversation. These are single lines of text typed into the entry box.

Comment: There's nothing built-in to tkiner that does what you want. You could probably do something like it by using a `tkinter.Text` widget in conjunction with custom event handlers—basically creating a custom text editor widget of your own design.

Answer (score 0):

I think it honestly depends on what you're trying to accomplish with your program. I mean you could easily make a group of arrays with different responses and use if/else loops paired with input functions to make a responsive chatbot. That would be the "easy" route and I'm literally working on a mini project like this.